# Why does this subnetting class app freeze up?

Tags: c++, ip, subnet

This code is C/C++ and runs without warnings or debug messages. I'm using Code::blocks with the GNU GCC compiler. This app worked perfectly once, then somewhere along the lines I messed up without noticing. Now every time it will allow a ip address input, but then freeze up and close. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int ip[3];
char * inputIP;
int x;
string classValue;

void subnetClass()
{
if (x==0) classValue="Error: first octet may not be zero.";
if (x>0 && x<=126) classValue="Class A";
if (x==127) classValue="Loopback Address";
if (x>=128 && x<=191) classValue="Class B";
if (x>=192 && x<=223) classValue="Class C";
if (x>=224 && x<=239) classValue="Class D";
if (x>=240 && x<=255) classValue="Class E";
if (x>255) classValue="Error: an octet may not be more than 255.";

cout << classValue << endl;
}


int main()
{
cout << "Enter IP address in dotted-decimal form." << endl;
cin >> inputIP;
scanf(inputIP, "%d.%d.%d.%d" , &ip[0],&ip[1],&ip[2],&ip[3]);
int x=ip[0];
subnetClass();

return 0;
}
```

Build Log:

> Checking for existence: C:...\IP subnetting app\bin\Debug\IP subnetting app.exe
>
> Executing: "C:...\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:...\IP subnetting app\bin\Debug\IP subnetting app.exe"  (in C:...\IP subnetting app.)
>
> Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 27 seconds)

Comment: Indentation, please. And your program is either C++ or C; it cannot be both. (Doesn't look anything like C to me.) Did you run it through a debugger? How can it freeze up _and_ close?

Comment: You extract a string into a C-style string that does not exist (`inputIP` is just an uninitialised pointer).

Comment: You declare `int ip[3]`, an array of three ints (indices 0..2) then write to `ip[3]` which is past the end of the array.

Comment: You do realize that the whole notion of class A, B, C, D, E networks has been obsolete for years, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have worked with a little help from sheer luck even if you messed things up later, I believe. More or less everything is wrong. First you read the line into the area pointed to by uninitialized pointer (or maybe you read the pointer value, I'm not even sure what `>> (char*)` is supposed to do). You better change the definition to

```
std::string inputIP;
```

then you try to parse it used `scanf` and pass this pointer as a format string. What you meant is using `sscanf`. Assuming you changed the `inputIP` type, you can use

```
sscanf(inputIP.c_str(),"%d....
```

Then you assign to local main variable `x` that shadows global, which remains uninitialized when you use it in the function. Just remove the `int` part in the assignment like this:

```
x=ip[0];
```

and make the `ip` array of four elements.

```
int ip[4];
```

Then it may work. Unless I missed something else.

And one more thing: if you use some source control (for instance using `git` you may start new project in no time) then you'd know what you've changed when you mess up, just commit early, commit often.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a variable 'x' that is hiding the global one.

`int x=ip[0];`

However, don't do it this way.  Add an int parameter to subnetClass and pass in the value that way, and remove the global variable.

Really, removing all of your globals should be a goal and easy to accomplish.  Several are only used in main().

Answer (score 0):

Use `sscanf` instead of `scanf`